Students try to cheat and steal tests
There is a movie I saw many years ago and I can't find it anywhere. I think it was from the early 2000s.
It is about a group of friends who break into their school so they can steal the answers to a test so they can cheat. Through the course of the movie, the main guy explains all of the cheating methods he has perfected. They get caught by the janitor trying to steal the answers and one of them when asked what his name is answers "Jimmy Carter".
I don't remember much of the movie because I was too young when I watched it but I remember it has a Ferris Bueller's Day Off kind of vibe. Please help me find this movie!!
Just so you know, it is not the movie with Scarlett Johansson in it.

Hi. Do you remember what year\decade the movie was from? Where\when did you see it, exactly?

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

You're looking for Cheats from 2002.

While other kids at the elite North Point Academy spend countless hours studying, Handsome Davis sees it as nothing more than a system of control over your mind. That's why Handsome and his three best friends Sammy, Victor and the cribsheet genius Applebee have banded together and found ways to cheat on their tests all through their school years. 

When the janitor catches them, Handsome says his name is Jimmy Carter. Here's the trailer:



